# Exporting zipfilesets

Tags: ant

We are currently generating a zip file using multiple  targets as follows.

```
<zipfile>
    <zipfileset dir="alpha" prefix="alpha" />
    <zipfileset dir="beta" prefix="alpha" excludes="*.bar" />
    <zipfileset dir="gamma/G" prefix="gamma" /> 
</zipfile>
```

A requirement has come up in that we need to generate (and include) a list of the included files and their corresponding MD5 checksum values.

If we use a `<fileset>`/`<patternset>`/`<pathconvert>` combination, I can get a text file containing all the files, and generate from there. However, I can't seem to find a way to do this with `<zipfileset />` targets.

Is there a way to do a 'dry-run' and obtain a list of the  targets that will be included? Or is there a (simple) method of extracting the required information from the generated ZIP itself?

Comment: [From the manual of Ant's ZIP task] includesfile: the name of a file. Each line of this file is taken to be an include pattern.  [See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html ]

Answer (score 1):

If you have already generated file (with checksum) you can just add it with help of another [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).

The sample:

```
<target name="ziptest">
    <zip destfile="${src}\output.zip">
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <include name="dir1\*"/>
            <include name="dir2\fileprefix*"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <!-- You have property with filename: file.name.checksum-->
            <include name="${file.name.checksum}"/>
        </fileset>
    </zip>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was more asking how to export the files that will be matched in the `<zipfileset>` targets out to a file, so that I can use this to generate the checksum file.